# Flutter auto_route guard not intercepting

Tags: flutter

Am trying to use flutter "auto_route" package for routing. I have added a Guard for one of the routes to check if its authenticated or not. But when i try to navigate to that route, the guard is not getting fired.

Comment: Please add the code where the problem is happening, thanks.

Comment: @James figured out the issue. Guard doesn't work on TabRoutes.